# Connect docker container from Web Browser

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I've created a web-service, which i'd packed into docker conatiner. This web-service consists of java backend part and JSP pages. Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'restaurant'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5433/restaurant
      - SPRING_LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5433/restaurant
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=****
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
      - POSTGRES_DB=restaurant
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGPORT= 5433
```

So I have 2 containers - one with database (***db***) and another with service(***app***). They communicate in a right way. And this application works, if I start it locally with no docker.  After packing it into containers, I successfully start application:

[Here I have successfully started my containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHB03.png)

BUT!! When I try to connect it through Chrome, I get the Error.

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5t6Z.png)

I was surfing through internet and found - I have to use link http://localhost:8080/, because I made port forwarding:

```
    ports:
  - "8080:80"
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help me please - how to connect to container through browser?

Comment: "*I have to go to link `http://localhost:8081`*" - In the `docker-compose`, we configured that host-port `8080` is forwarded to container-port `80`. So if we should access anything, It should be `http://localhost:8080`. --- I am going to take a shot in the blue here. If not reconfigured, spring-boot starts on port `8080`, so I suspect that we have to re-write the port-mapping from `8080:80` to `8080:8080`. --- If this does not help, we need a [MRE], e.g. a github repository.

Comment: @Turing85 has right.
For a more extended explanation visit
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67120401/13247841

Comment: @Turing85 thanks. It helped - I mean re-writing the port-mapping from 8080:80 to 8080:8080